# How do I over lap three or more render layers in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, render-layers

I'm trying to place three images on top of each other using the compositor. I don't really know how to do it, I think I could use the alpha over approach but I'd need to use the alphas of both the other images to do that but I cant find a node for adding alphas. Does anybody happen to have any ideas on how to get this effect?

[image: My render nodes, the first two on the left go in front of the grey image]

Comment: Overlap 2 images A and B. The result is an image - call it A again, bring image B, and simply repeat what you just did.

Comment: yeah except I need the alpha of the combined images not of one or the other

Comment: Aaah I see the "Alpha Over" doesn't actually output alpha. If you created an example .blend it would be an easier entry to try to help, I'm not sure what the formula is, would have to play around with it for a bit...

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else finds this useful, here's how I fixed it. Take the mask from the outliners and add them together, invert the colour and use that as the factor for the alpha over.
[image: 3 layer render composition without loosing outlines]